# When building containers why is using Java Generics better than using the Object Class? (Java Generics & DataStructures)

Tags: java, generics, containers, type-safety, collect

So I have been reviewing my data structures and came across an interesting thought regarding Java generics and the `Object` class. I have implemented and run a "generic bag" in two different ways **(Notice below: IObjectBag.java, ObjectBag.java, IGenericBag.java, and GenericBag.java)** and have used them both **(Notice: Below main.java and Output)**. I have removed some of the unnecessary code as per stack overflow rules but if you want the full implementation, let me know.

Also, I have researched the topic in many websites, books and courses in addition to looking at the source code for the `ArrayList` class [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) and I understand that my `GenericBag` is a better option than my `ObjectBag` but not well enough to explain it in a practical way during an interview. And I am confused that my `GenericBag` uses more casting operations than my `ObjectBag` in its implementation (see `Remove` and `PrintBag`).

1. So, other than the syntactic sugar, why is my `GenericBag` better? Please use my classes as examples.
2. Are there any important differences in runtime/overhead/space/time I am not noticing?
3. How would you answer this question or expect it to be answered in an interview?

**Bonus questions**: If you want, please answer the bonus questions in the `Main` and `GenericBag` comments (I think I can answer them myself though, just want to hear your opinion).

`IObjectBag` interface:

```java
public interface IObjectBag {
    void add(Object item);
    Object remove(Object item) throws NoSuchElementException;
    boolean isEmpty();
    int find(Object item);
    Object get(int index);
    int numItems();
}
```

`ObjectBag` class:

```java
public class ObjectBag implements IObjectBag {
    private Object [] items; // the java class attribute that will hold out "ints"
    private int numItems;
    
    public static void printBag(IObjectBag bag) {
        for(int i = 0; i < bag.numItems(); i++) {
            System.out.println(bag.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    public ObjectBag(int size) {
        this.items = new Object[size]; // fills array with null values
        this.numItems = 0;
    }
    
    public void add(Object item){
        // adds item to end of bag
    }
    
    public Object remove(Object item) {
        int index = this.find(item);

        if(index == -1) throw new NoSuchElementException("oops nothing found");
        
        Object out = this.items[index];
        
        this.items[index] = null;
        this.numItems -= 1;
        
        if(index + 1 != this.items.length && this.items[index + 1] != null) {  
            for(int i = index; i < this.items.length; i++) {
                if(i + 1 != this.items.length) this.items[i] = this.items[i + 1];
            }
            
            this.items[this.items.length - 1] = null;
        }
        
        return out;
    }
    
    public int find(Object item) {
        // return index given item or -1 
    }
    
    public Object get(int index) {
        // returns item given index
    }
    
}
```

`IGenericBag` class:

```java
public interface IGenericBag <T> {
    void add(T item);
    T remove(T item) throws NoSuchElementException;
    boolean isEmpty();
    int find(T item);
    T get(int index);
}
```

`GenericBag` class:

```java
public class GenericBag<T> implements IGenericBag<T> {
    // private T[] items; can't use this b/c see comment in constructor
    private Object[] items;
    private int numItems;
    
    public static void printBag(GenericBag bag) {
        for(int i = 0; i < bag.numItems(); i++) {
            System.out.println(bag.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    public GenericBag(int size) {
        // this.items = new T[size]; Bonus: throws generic array creation error (why?)
        this.items = new Object[size];
        this.numItems = 0;
    }
    
    public void add(T item){
        this.items[this.numItems] = item;
        this.numItems += 1;
    }
    
    public T remove(T item) {
        int index = this.find(item);

        if(index == -1) throw new NoSuchElementException("oops nothing found");
        
        T out = (T) this.items[index];
        
        this.items[index] = null;
        this.numItems -= 1;
        
        if(index + 1 != this.items.length && this.items[index + 1] != null) {  
            for(int i = index; i < this.items.length; i++) {
                if(i + 1 != this.items.length) this.items[i] = this.items[i + 1];
            }
            
            this.items[this.items.length - 1] = null;
        }
        
        return out;
    }
    
    public int find(Object item) {
        // given object return index or throw exception
    }
    
    public T get(int index) {
        return (T) this.items[index];
    }
    
}
```

`Main` class:

```java
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello StackOverFlow!");
        Object int1 = new Integer(1);
        Object int2 = new Integer(2);
        Object int3 = new Integer(3);
        
        
        /* using my object bag ************************************************/
        System.out.println("using my object bag");
        IObjectBag myObjectBag = new ObjectBag(3);
                
        myObjectBag.add(int1);
        myObjectBag.add(int2);
        myObjectBag.add(int3);
        myObjectBag.remove(int2);
        
        ObjectBag.printBag(myObjectBag);
        
        /* using my generic bag ***********************************************/
        System.out.println("using generic bag");
        
        
        // Bonus Question: using object like above causes error at add method (why?)
        Integer int4 = new Integer(4); 
        Integer int5 = new Integer(5);
        Integer int6 = new Integer(6);
        
        GenericBag<Integer> myGenericBag = new GenericBag<Integer>(3); 
        //Bonus Question: using Interface decllaration like above causes error in print bag (why?) 
        
        myGenericBag.add(int4);
        myGenericBag.add(int5);
        myGenericBag.add(int6);
        myGenericBag.remove(int4);
        
        GenericBag.printBag(myGenericBag);
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
Hello StackOverFlow!
using my object bag
1
3
using generic bag
5
6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with your ObjectBag that are 'automaticaly' solved by the **type safety** offered by your GenericBag implementation:

- Accessing an entry returns Object, at this stage you do not know of what type Object is.
- You can insert any types of Objects (mixed) e.g a String and an Integer into the same list, this is an anti pattern and causes non readable code (try it with your Generics bag!)
- Because your compiler knows the type of your GenericBag after you have declared it, at any stage of your code if you hover over your genericBag instance you will know its type, this makes your code more readable and also extendable for other people

Generics also offer way more, imagine you want your GenericBag to only accept numbers, then you could write it as follows:

```
public class GenericBag<T extends Number>
```

My suggestion for you is to read some articles on Java basics and especially Generics, having a praxis based way of learning is a good thing, but there are plenty articles that can give you some very nice theoretical insight on the matter.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

Answer (score 1):

Reason of using, let's say, `GenericBag<String>` over `ObjectBag` is essentially the same as for using `String` (or any other type) over an `Object`:

**Type safety.**

You declare that some method returns a collection of Strings and nothing else, thus preventing yourself from putting there other objects, or trying to treat what you get from a bag as some other type. This might sound stupid when you have 100 lines of code, but this may save you lot of debugging time when you work with decent codebase.

Although, type safety is not a silver bullet, it is just an instrument, that some people find useful and some don't. I'm pretty sure it is a popular holywar topic for any programming forum.

If you feel comfortable working without this paradigm (Javascript background, right?), you might consider trying some dynamically typed language like Python instead of Java.